# Getting real iPhone device IMEI on Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am followed this [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/54272/how-to-get-the-imei-number) 
It is able to detect IMEI for iPhone simulator but for a real device it returns an empty string. Could you please tell me what has changed or if there's any permission needed for this. I am a beginner in ios development.

Comment: You can't. This is not allowed anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer possible: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/31122

> In general, iOS does not let you get at persistent unique identifiers
>   (the IMEI, the UDID, the Wi-Fi MAC address, and so on).

Comment: Ok actually this one liner is able to uniquely identify a device : https://montemagno.com/unique-device-id-for-mobile-apps/